# Designing a chat application in android | communicating with a remote server

Tags: android, http

I am trying to implement a HTTP based chat here. All the chat messages are supposed to be stored at a remote server.

Now as a receiver, i need to check periodically if i have received any new chat messages from others, by communicating with the remote server. What is the best practice to implement this periodic checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first say XMPP is the best way to go about getting chat on an android, there are [android libraries](https://code.google.com/p/asmack/) to deal with it. That being said I think what you want to look into is [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). Simply Comet is the web methodology for doing data 'push' so that you do not have to poll a server frequently to see if there is new data, aka chat messages, to render. Some tools you might look into is [lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/) or something like [Continuations in Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations). Tomcat also has [support for Comet](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet) that you could use, though any pure Apache solution I'm not entirely familiar with (Or if that's a good idea at all). Goodluck!